# Camel REST DSL enableCORS only working for GET

Tags: rest, apache-camel, cors

I have set up a simple REST interface using Camel 2.14.1 or the 2.15.0 Snapshot.

```
   <restConfiguration bindingMode="auto" component="jetty"
                host="127.0.0.1" port="8082" enableCORS="true">
```

In both versions, enabling CORS only works for GET requests but not POST or PUT for example, since they require an OPTIONS request before that. But the browser will always get an 404 error, because the OPTIONS method is not allowed, even the docs clearly state that this should be the case if you set `enableCORS="true"`. 
http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html

> Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE,
>   OPTIONS, CONNECT, PATCH

I have also tried to do this manually by setting the crosshead, but still no luck.

```
<restConfiguration bindingMode="auto" component="jetty"
            host="127.0.0.1" port="8082" enableCORS="true">
            <corsHeaders key="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
            <corsHeaders key="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"/>
            <corsHeaders key="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS"/>
            </restConfiguration>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think Jetty may reject the OPTIONS before rest-dsl has a chance to react

Comment: I logged a ticket to look into this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8373 - But if you have an easy way of reproducing this issue or can provide more value information, then that helps. For example what content-type do you try to send? eg maybe if you have samples of HTTP reuqests you send

Comment: You are right, indeed there is no OPTIONS reply from rest-dsl. I worked around this by adding a manual OPTIONS endpoint like this <from uri="jetty://http://127.0.0.1:8082/transfer?matchOnUriPrefix=true&amp;httpMethodRestrict=OPTIONS" />, nonetheless it doesn't work if you have a general endpoint like jetty://http://127.0.0.1:8082?matchOnUriPrefix=true